# Simple query with variable parameters

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have three queries which I would like to consolidate into one query which can accept a variable length of `WHERE` arguments; I cannot remember for the life of me how to do this.

```
PreparedStatement queryOne = connection.prepareStatement
("SELECT columnOne, columnTwo, columnThree FROM tableOne WHERE columnOne = ?;" );

PreparedStatement queryTwo = connection.prepareStatement
("SELECT columnOne, columnTwo, columnThree FROM tableOne WHERE columnTwo = ?;" );

PreparedStatement queryThree = connection.prepareStatement
("SELECT columnOne, columnTwo, columnThree FROM tableOne WHERE columnOne = ? AND columnTwo = ?;" );
```

Comment: How do you mean "consolidate"? Do you want a query that returns the union of the results, the intersection of the results, or something else?

Comment: I would like to create a single PreparedStatement which accepts a variable length of WHERE statements.

Comment: Yes, If you mean "consolidate" a UNION might help.

Comment: I don't think you can have a single prepared statement that has a variable number of WHERE clause conditions, for the same reason that the field names in a prepared statement cannot be placeholders. How would the dbms know how to prepare it?

Comment: So it can only be done without prepared statements I assume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question, feel free to chime in on whether this is bad practice or not.

```
String columnOne = getValue();
String columnTwo = getValue();
String queryString = "SELECT columnOne, columnTwo, columnThree FROM tableOne"

if (columnOne != null && columnTwo != null)
    queryString = queryString + "WHERE columnOne = ? AND columnTwo = ?"
else if (columnOne != null)
    queryString = queryString + "WHERE columnOne = ?"
else if (columnTwo != null)
    queryString = queryString + "WHERE columnTwo = ?"

PreparedStatement query = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
```

Answer (score 1):

All three queries select the same columns from the same table, so their union can be easily done in one statement:

```
SELECT columnOne, columnTwo, columnThree 
  FROM tableOne 
 WHERE columnOne = ?
    or columnTwo = ?
    or (columnOne = ? AND columnTwo = ?)
```

Comment: If I only assign a value to the first ? will the statement execute properly?

Comment: @Dennis - No. You need to supply a value for each of the placeholders.

Comment: never get to check the third condition, because this overlapped with the first and second,